# How to download JSON dataset from REST API

Tags: python, powershell, api, rest

I need to get to REST API and download a JSON dataset.
The documentation says how to do this in Python:

```
import requests
    data={
    'sso_operation': 'authenticate_user',
    'user': 'joe.blogs@gmial.com',
    'password': 'this_1s_Private'
}
r1 = requests.post('WEBSSO_URL', data=data, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
r2 = requests.get('TARGET URL', cookies=r1.cookies, verify=False, allow_redirects=True)
print (r2.status_code)
print(r2.text)
```

It looks like two step post and get. Only thing I can figure out is this:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
    $user = "xxxx.com"
    $password = "xxxx"
    $restURL = "xxx"
    $headers = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + 
    [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("${user}@${account}:${password}"))}
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $restURL -Headers $headers
    $response.content
```

Can anybody help to have this 2 step post\get ?

Answer (score 0):

As we don't know the documentation you are referring to, I would start with the Post method in this fashion. I placed your `data` variable in the header, as I would usually authenticate through the header and send separately a JSON body. If I am mistaken, remove the header and place everything into `$body`. If the result is an authentication key, it will be stored in `$postResult` which you can reuse.

```
$header = @{
  'sso_operation' = 'authenticate_user'
  'user' = 'your.user'
  'password' = 'your.password'
}

$body = @{
  'JSON' = 'body'
} | ConvertTo-Json

$postResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header -Body $body -ContentType 'application/json'
```

I recommend to use `Invoke-RestMethod` if you interact with JSON format. I now assume that the response from the 'Post' call returns your key which I placed in the header.

```
$header = @{
  'Authentication' = $postResult
}
$getResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $header
```